# how to implement java service

Tags: java

I want to create service using `Java` service provider inferface. Please help me how to create service in Java.

Thanks

Comment: -1 for complete lack of detail

Comment: A little more of background would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service provider interface (or SPI) for short is a concrete  implementation of an API formalized as a set of java interfaces.

So the short answer is to create a set of classes which implement the API interfaces for which you want to create a concrete implementation.

[Here is an article](http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/3848881/Service-Provider-Interface-Creating-Extensible-Java-Applications.htm) which goes into more detail.

Answer (score -1):

There's a pretty useful script to wrap up a java app as a windows service here:
http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can look to java.util.ServiceLoader to see how you can use it.